# Turning Array Data Into Percent Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I have a program that uses DataTables and it is currently displaying the total value of all of the data entries while also displaying the totals for each category (in this case by office).  I would also like to make it so that you can can see what percentage of the total each office is contributing.  I am having difficulty figuring out how to iterate through the array and grab the values so that I can calculate them correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#reportTable').DataTable(
        {
            dom: 'Blfript', // Blfrtip
            buttons:
            [
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    footer: true,
                    className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-file',
                    title: 'Report',
                    filename: 'Report',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    exportOptions:
                    {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    footer: true, 
                    className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt',
                    title: 'Report',
                    filename: 'Report',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    exportOptions:
                    {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    title: 'Report',
                    footer: true,
                    className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate',
                    exportOptions:
                    {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    }
                },
                    {
                        extend: 'print',
                        footer: true,
                        className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-print',
                        text: 'Print',
                        title: ' ',
                        autoPrint: true,
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                        exportOptions:
                        {
                            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                        },
                        // Format exported footer (NOT WORKING)
                        customize: function (win)
                        {
                            var body = $(win.document.body).find('table tfoot');
                            $(body).append($(body).find('tr:eq(0)').clone());
                            var row = $(body).find('tr').last();
                            //$(row).find('th').text('NEW');
                            $(row).find('th:eq(7)').text('First column');
                        },                      
                    }
            ],
            "footerCallback": function (row, start, end, display)
            {
                var api = this.api(),data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function (i)
                {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                            i : 0;
                };                  

                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(5)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b)
                    {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Total over all filtered pages
                if (api
                    .column(5,
                        {
                            search: 'applied'
                        })
                    .data()
                    .length)
                        {
                            pageTotal = api
                            .column(5, 
                                {
                                    search: 'applied'
                                })
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) 
                        {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        });
                } else {
                    pageTotal = 0;
                }   
                
                // Total by office               
                var office = api.column(2).data().sort().unique().toArray();
                var totals = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < office.length; i++) totals.push(0);
                
                for (var j = 0; j < totals.length; j++) {
                    var temp = temp + parseFloat(totals[j]);
                }
                var percent = (temp / total) * 100;   
                api.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).every(function ()
                {
                    var data = this.data();
                    totals[office.indexOf(data[2])] += intVal(data[5]);
                });

                // Remove any offices that have a "0" result
                html = [];            
                for (var j = 0; j < office.length; j++) {
                    if (totals[j] > 0) html.push(office[j] + ': ' + totals[j].toFixed(2) + ' (' + percent + '%)');
                } 

                // Update footer
                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(html.length === 0 ? "" : html.join('</br>') + '</br>' + '$' + pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' filtered total' + '</br>' + '$' + total.toFixed(2) + ' total'); 
            },
        });
    }
);

$(document).ready
    (
        function ()
        {
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push
            (
                function (settings, data, dataIndex)
                {
                    var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
                    var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(data[0]);
                    if (min === null && max === null) { return true; }
                    if (min === null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
                    if(max === null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
                    if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    return false;
                }
            );
       
            $("#min").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
            $("#max").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
            var table = $('#reportTable').DataTable();

            // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
            $('#min, #max').change
            (
                function ()
                {
                    table.draw();
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jszip-2.5.0,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> 
   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script> 
</head>

<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin: 10px; padding: 5px;">Start Date:</td>
            <td><input name="min" id="min" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin: 10px; padding: 5px;">End Date:</td>
            <td><input name="max" id="max" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%" class="display" id="reportTable" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/total.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/daterange.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please don't post working code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just include your executable code in your question as a "code snippet" (on the toolbar when you are composing your question) as I have done for you.

Comment: When looking for a percentage of a total, it is usually 'simple' to do because you are working from dynamic data (and can pull such calculations from other functions - like PHP or other things).  In your example you show stagnant data, which is both unlikely to be a real-world situation and harder to work with.  Where are you getting this data? (i.e., where is the dynamic info so it can be considered for other calculations)  Otherwise, you need to keep a 'running total' of the numbers, then run another loop to calculate percentages and then update each line (like I said, a 'mess'..)

Comment: Sorry about not using the code snippet.  I'll be sure to do that in the future!

The data is being pulled off of an SQL database and is not hard coded into my program.  I just found some random information to use for testing purposes on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing with this today as I needed to distract myself from something else and came up with this, it doesn't do everything you need but it's not far off:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#reportTable').DataTable({
            "footerCallback": function (row, start, end, display){
                const intVal = i => typeof i === 'string' ? parseInt(i.replace(/[\$,]/g, ''), 10) : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0, 
                    api = this.api(),
                    obj = {
                        total: api.column(5).data().reduce((a, b) => a + intVal(b), 0),
                        offices: []
                    };
                api.column(2).data().sort().unique().toArray().forEach(office => {
                    obj.offices.push({
                        office,
                        total: 0
                    });
                });
                api.rows().every(a => {
                    let d = api.row(a).data()
                    obj.offices.find(x => x.office === d[2]).total += intVal(d[5]);
                });
                const footer = [`Grand total: ${numeral(obj.total).format('$0,0.00')}`];
                obj.offices.forEach(o => {
                    footer.push(`<strong>${o.office}</strong>: ${numeral(o.total).format('$0,0.00')} (${((o.total * 100) / obj.total).toFixed(2)}%)`)
                });
                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(footer.join("<br>")); 
            },
        });
    }
);
```

Hope it [helps](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lw0juen8/) a little...

Comment: Thank you!  That will definitely get the ball rolling.  This has been driving me nuts. :D